# Query rows for matching JSONB column where key ends with a name and key value is a specific value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Given the following rows with a `jsonb` column `details`. How do I write a query so that records where the key name ends with `_col` with value `B` are selected. So records with ids 1, 2.

`id  | details
1   | { "one_col": "A", "two_col": "B" }
2   | { "three_col": "B" }
3   | { another: "B" }`

So far I've only find ways to match based on the value, not the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) which gives json objects as pairs `(key, value)`:

```
with the_data(id, details) as (
values
(1, '{ "one_col": "A", "two_col": "B" }'::jsonb),
(2, '{ "three_col": "B" }'),
(3, '{ "another": "B" }')
)

select t.*
from the_data t,
lateral jsonb_each_text(details)
where key like '%_col'
and value = 'B';

 id |             details              
----+----------------------------------
  1 | {"one_col": "A", "two_col": "B"}
  2 | {"three_col": "B"}
(2 rows)
```